# firefox having "#;" in the addressbar

Tags: php, javascript, html, firefox

Why does firefox(haven't tested in another browser) has problems loading form values when a `#;` is in the addressbar?
If i have an `<input type='radio' checked="checked">`, the presence of this element in the addressbar may lead to the input not actually getting checked(as expected)

How can i avoid this behavior?

---

Example code:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr" style="min-height:100%;">
    <head>
        <title>stuff2test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body class="popup" >
        <form action="" id="frm">
            <a href="#;" onClick="alert('added');">add #; to addressbar, and refresh</a>

            <?php $rnd = mt_rand(1, 4); ?>

            <label for="r_v1"> <input id="r_v1" type="radio" value="v1" <?php if($rnd==1){ echo 'checked="checked"';}?> name="r"></input> checked?</label>
            <label for="r_v2"> <input id="r_v2" type="radio" value="v2" <?php if($rnd==2){ echo 'checked="checked"';}?> name="r"></input> checked?</label>
            <label for="r_v3"> <input id="r_v3" type="radio" value="v3" <?php if($rnd==3){ echo 'checked="checked"';}?> name="r"></input> checked?</label>

        </form>

        <button onClick="getElementById('frm').submit();" type="button">submit</button>

        <br/>
        RND: <?php echo $rnd;?>
        <?php
        if($rnd>0 && $rnd<=3){
            echo "Checkbox {$rnd} should be checked";
        }
        ?>
        <br/>

        <?php
            var_dump($_GET);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit2: cleaned the code a little, added an echo

Comment: When isn't the checkbox getting checked? When users click on it or using JS? It must be something else, because a pund sign in the url doesn't / shouldn't matter. Tested with FF 5

Comment: Where does # come into play when you have a radio??? Example please

Comment: When you add `#something` to the URL then the page does not get refreshed.

Comment: Can you please post the html for the form that's giving you trouble, in particular the actual form tag?

Comment: Why are you adding a semi colon to the url at the same time as the hash, is that just a typo?

Comment: I'm not seeing the described behaviour on this test using you example code: http://testing.subdmedia.com/so/6775085/. Can you more accurately descibe the steps to reproduce it?

Comment: havin `#test`int he url will cause the browser to scroll to the element with `id=test`, `;` on the other hand dosen;t exist in the page... not having anything there scrolls to the top of the page(not sure i remember correctly, we're using this for a really long time now)

Comment: weird, i can reproduce it without the "#;" in the addressbar now, on the link you provided. Just go in the page and hit refresh. The checked element should vary. It stais the same in my browser(firefox)

Comment: Have you tried with CTRL+F5?  I think the behaviour you're seeing is because FF is caching the checked attribute for the boxes. I get the behaviour you describe  intermittently with F5, and never with CTRL+F5.

Comment: yes, ctrl+f5 works, but it aint a real fix:) and having cached pages it a plus in web-development, i dont want to have to regenerate things for every request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From reading the comments on the question, the answer seems clear.

The problem is that Firefox tries to remember the state of the form when you reload the page, which includes which checkboxes are checked and which aren't. So even though you vary the default values in the HTML on reload, Firefox sees it as the same form and ignores the defaults set in the HTML in favor of what it has saved from before the reload.

I've heard you can disable this behavior by supplying the HTTP header `Cache-Control: no-store`, or by specifying `autocomplete="off"` on the form elements. But I have not tested either solution personally. Or you could use Javascript to reset the form on page load (either with the form object's `reset()` or by explicitly setting each field's value).

Comment: I've ended up using `header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");` and still nothing..

Comment: Calling .reset() for the form seems to do the trick, not sure about other implications though, i'll have to check it further(the real form has lots of inputs)

Answer (score 6):

You have links like this, right?

```
<a href="#">link</a>
```

And you do something with them using JavaScript (here: jQuery too), right?

```
$('a').click(function() {
    alert(1);
});
```

You need to add `return false` at the end of the function.

```
$('a').click(function() {
    alert(1);

    return false;
});
```

**Edit:**

After looking at your code... Do **NOT** use inline JavaScript!

You need some element that will do something on click? Just add class, ID - you name it... so you can distinguish between elements and then...

```
$('a.my_class').click(function() { // $('a#my_id')
    // All you need to do.

    return false; // For preventing browser to add '#' after current link (if you have 'href="#"').
});
```

Comment: or use `<a href="javascript:void(0)">link</a>`

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to do that, but in some cases i cant do that(legacy, old code, in the process of being rebuild, but ituses some incompatibilities for now). I'm wondering why is it happening, and if there is an easier way to prevent it(without tyoughing big chunks of legacy code)

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm right but I think that in jQuery event callbacks `return false` does not work, you need to call the `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: @Molecule: please don't use inline JS!

Comment: @Skirmantas: `return false;` does both `.stopPropagation()` and `.preventDefault()` so it would be enough ;)

Comment: @Peehaa, Molecule - it is WORSE than inline javascript to have href="javascript:anything"

Comment: Yes, inline js is ugly, but this is not my choice, i'm just trying to clean things up a little. It dosent create any technical problem using inline js, just uglifies the code... so it shouldn't matter

Comment: @Quamis Why don't you just use onclick="something()" instead of href="javascript:something()"? Using the href is just ugly. And it may confuse the user when they look at the status bar and it has some code in it they might not click it sometimes. When you use onclick, it's better. Like this: `<a href="#" onclick="something();return false;">Click</a>`

Comment: Even better to **do not** use `inline JavaScript`! Is that so hard? :)

Comment: @Nathan, if you look at the example code i provided, that how i use it;)

Comment: @daGrevis, i know its not a clean way to do things, but as long as i'm maintaing a big pile of..code, i cant afford to rewrite the whole thing, and even if i would... why would i?

Comment: @daGrevis What's wrong with using onclick? It doesn't effect the way the code works...

Comment: @Quamis I see now. But I still don't see the big deal of using onclick, it doesn't effect the result of the code, so what is daGrevis's problem with onclicks?

Comment: Its not a problem. Its just the best practices, plus, it will increase readability of code. :)

Answer (score 1):

The hash (#) is a special character in a URL.  Anything that comes after it is not sent to the server, so if you're using hashed URLs you really need to use POST (or an AJAX request to a non hashed URL if GET is essential) to send your form data.

An alternative is to implement something similar to Google's [_escaped_fragment_](https://code.google.com/intl/de/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html) to ensure that the contents of your URL after the hash will be sent to the server.

Comment: interesting, but still dosen;t explain why form data may get corrupted in the process

Answer (score 0):

I use that "trick" massively, and don't have problems, because I use the input type="submit" control.

If you replace the line:

```
<button onClick="getElementById('frm').submit();" type="button">submit</button>
```

with

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

solve the problem without changing the anchors and without touching the javascript code.

Good Luck!

Comment: I cant use submit button unfortunately. The layout of the form(the production code) has to call the submit code in a button positioned in an fixed position(or in some cases programatically from js)..